# Is there a way to add Business Intelligence Projects templates to Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

From what I understand, it should automatically have it installed. What I have installed right now is SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2008 Developer.

Thanks,
Fahad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools, you will see the `Business Intelligence project` templates in Visual Studio 2008.

So, make sure that you installed SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools and not just the Express edition.

Check the following link to understand which SQL Server editions support Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS).

[**Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2 - Development Tools**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Dev_tools)

Follow this link to find the steps to install SQL Server client tools.

[**SQL Server 2008 Client Tools Installation**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1807/sql-server-2008-client-tools-installation/)

#### Update:

If you have the SQL Server 2008 R2 Client tools installed, you should see a folder in the `Windows Start --> All Programs` option. Within that you should see `SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio`. If you don't, then you don't have the client tools installed.

[image: BIDS]

You can also open Visual Studio 2008 and navigate to `Help --> About Microsoft Visual Studio` and look for the following components to be installed.

- SQL Server Analysis Services
- SQL Server Reporting Services
- SQL Server Integration Services

[image: Help]

Comment: Is there a way for me to check whether or not I installed SQL Server client tools? Or do I have to do a fresh install?

Also thanks for the reply

Comment: Ah so it looks like I do not have client tools installed. How would you recommend I go about installing them? And thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

you need to install SSIS, SSAS and SSRS (which come with SQL Server 2008 installation, you just have to pick the option).

Once you install any them you will have access to BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio), which is visual studio with the BI templates

Comment: I have them all installed. Do they all need to be running in order for me to get BIDS?